# mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111) when trying to connect

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Site is using wordpress and hosted on AWS EC2 Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Database is AWS RDS

I was trying to download a copy of our site using mysqldump
but when running the command
`mysqldump -u [user] -p [database_name] > [database_name].sql`

it gives an error
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111) when trying to connect

Why is this happening?

note: I was able to connect from the ec2 instance using
`mysql -h [host] -P [port] --enable-cleartext-plugin --user=[user] --password`

and can connect to mysql shell.

I would really appreciate answers and thank you in advance

Comment: use the host and port option with `mysqldump` like `mysql`. Depending on version, look for a cleartext-plugin option too.

Comment: wow! it works! You're awesome. I also added the flag --column-statistics=0. Thank you for your help @danblack